# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'B:/...projects/admin/tsconfig.app.json'

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

Missing directory error. I have attached  [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL4KB.jpg) to make you understand it better. The file the is present in the parent folder but cannot be recognized by system. Suggestions please

```
PS B:\...\Project\Frontend\projects> npm start

> eshop@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory.
An unhandled exception occurred: error TS500: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'B:/Work/Projects/Ecommerce Website/capstone G5/Project/Frontend/projects/projects/admin/tsconfig.app.json'
    at Module.lstatSync (node:fs:1561:3)
    at NodeJSFileSystem.lstat (file:///B:/Work/Projects/Ecommerce%20Website/capstone%20G5/Project/Frontend/projects/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-TOKOIIBI.js:342:16)
    at calcProjectFileAndBasePath (file:///B:/Work/Projects/Ecommerce%20Website/capstone%20G5/Project/Frontend/projects/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-Q7TXFDI7.js:7361:29)
    at readConfiguration (file:///B:/Work/Projects/Ecommerce%20Website/capstone%20G5/Project/Frontend/projects/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-Q7TXFDI7.js:7386:39)
```

Comment: `admin` and `user` are 2 angular projects?, if so, try running `npm install` on each project. From the picture posted, I see node_modules has been added, it should be ignore to `git`...

Comment: Yes you are just right. I was my mistake the `admin` and `user` are not two projects they just two separate part of this angular frontend. I just have to put them inside a single `src`. Thanks for the helping and also sorry for asking such silly questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because I had two components for this front-end application, both of which should have been kept in the `src` folder. The problem was resolved when I did, and the folder hierarchy appeared as follows:

[image: Folder Structure]

This was a very ignorant error, and I'll make sure not to ask a question of this nature on StackOverflow in the future.